# Enable multi-select on jQuery selectable on click

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to enable multi-select on jQuery selectable?

By multi-select I mean being able to select more than option by just clicking on it (similar to checkboxes) and if it is clicked on again, it deselects the option.

This is the code I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/vw9jL/1/

**HTML**

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">13</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">14</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">15</li>
</ol>​
```

**CSS**

```
#feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #C41C7B; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #C41C7B; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 450px; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 3px; float: left; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; text-align: center; }​
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
    });​
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind mouse down:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").bind('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable();
});​
```

[jSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vw9jL/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to have a default number of values selected? For example if I wanted 1 to 10 selected on page load

Comment: Always a good idea to accept answers in case you agree, you can always change your accept option.

Comment: @EmmanuelN Its only going to let me accept in the next two minutes. I was wondering how you have set certain blocks to be selected by default on page load - if that makes sense?

Comment: That make selectable behave as if control key has been hold down

Answer (score 0):

Control+Click your buttons in your fiddle ;)

Comment: Documentation also mentions ability to click and drag for multiple selections.