# JQuery Selectable on Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use jquery selectable on a table in Google Apps Script. I'm trying to be able to select multiple table rows at a time. I had it working, but now it's not. Any help would be appreciated!

I noticed the change when I added the `<tbody>` element. I tried changing both the `<style>` and function itself in multiple ways, but I can't seem to get it working as intended. I've looked through the documentation and some other questions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314684/enable-multi-select-on-jquery-selectable-on-click) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821175/clickable-table-rows-using-jquery-select), but I can't seem to make it work

Below is my entire `Index.html` file. I did not include the `Code.GS` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
  table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #table .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #table .ui-selected { background: #928bff; color: white; }
  #table { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #table tr { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>


<script>
     $(function() {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionsList)
           .getTeamArray();    
      });
</script>



<script>
function buildOptionsList(array2) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  var tbodyID = tableBody.setAttribute('id','tbody');

  array2.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

buildOptionsList(array2);

</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

 <script>
//need to edit something to get this working again.
$(function() {
  $("#table").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({filter: 'tr'});
});
</script>


 </head>



  <body>
    <div>TEST</div>
    <input id="searchInput" value="Type To Search">
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <th>GROUP</th>
        <th>CLUB</th> 
        <th>TEAM</th>
        <th>STATE</th>
      </tr>

    </table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here. I had conflicting versions of JQuery.

[.autocomplete is not a function Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error)